# How to adjust the label distance with error bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Normally, `vjsust =`  adjust the label distanace with the max y value, which is not beautiful when the sd is different, is it possible to adjust it with an equal relative distance with upper error bar?

In the following example, the `a` and `b` should be move down and `c` up, how to plot it?

```
df <- data.frame(dose=c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),
                 len=c(4.2, 10, 29.5), sd = c(0.2, 2, 5),
                 label = c('a', 'b', 'c'))

ggplot(df, aes(x = dose, y = len)) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = len, ymax = len + sd), width=.1, position=position_dodge(.6)) +
    geom_bar(position = position_dodge(), stat="identity", width=.4)+
    geom_text(aes(label = label,  angle = 0),vjust = -2.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `y` parameter in the `geom_text` aestethics to set up the position of the labels according to the error bars:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = dose, y = len)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = len, ymax = len + sd), width=.1, position=position_dodge(.6)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(), stat="identity", width=.4)+
  geom_text(aes(y = len + sd, label = label,  angle = 0),vjust = -2.5) +
  ylim(0, 40)
```

[image]